# can I add a question if I know it will be a duplicate of another question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have an existing question: [how to download a file using just bash and nothing else (no curl, wget, perl, etc.)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83926/how-to-download-a-file-from-bash-without-curl-wget-etc/83927#83927)

I think the question would find a wider audience by adding an additional question with a new title, e.g.

- "How to download a file using bash and /dev/tcp"

Is it ok to add a new question and mark it as a duplicate, pointing to the original question?

I don't think the original question should be changed to have the new title.  Both titles represent different use cases.

Comment: [This dr strange dupe post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) suggests some duplication is good so I'd think what you're suggesting would be a good thing but im not sure what the policy is on intensional duplication

Answer (score 2):

If you already know of the duplicate, then please don't.

In fact we encourage people to try to find any previous instances of the questiont that might satisfy them before asking. This is also why the "suggestions" list pops up while you are typing out a question. We want to minimize the work done by those answering questions that have already answered.

Only if you are unable to find any previous instance and you don't have an answer should you proceed to ask.

If your question is truly different in scope, then go ahead and ask, but just having a different title that you think is more attractive is not a good reason to ask a new question.

Comment: I just searched using the new title "How to download a file using bash and /dev/tcp" and it did not find the original post.

Comment: @Chris Obviously you've found it now. So your question is answered right?

Comment: @Caleb But he wants *other people* to be able to find an answer, like he did.